# Where does msinfo32.exe get it's data from?

Tags: windows, system-info

Specifically, I'm looking for where System Manufacturer and System Model are located. I'm assuming the registry somewhere.
I'm trying to identify the hardware for a few drive images i have backed up. Looking at the directories and driver's isn't telling me much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of that info is obtained from the registry at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System

and some of the other locales in **HARDWARE**.

The other system information such as **System Manufacturer** and **System Model** can only be obtained with calls to the Windows API.

Open up the WMIC.

> C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe

In the CLI type in `ComputerSystem Get Model, Manufacturer`

For a remote computer, you can use the following:

`%windir%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /node:"ComputerNameORIpAddress" ComputerSystem Get Model, Manufacturer`

Or if you need a password:

`%windir%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /node:"ComputerNameORIpAddress" /user:"domain\username" /password:"password" ComputerSystem Get Model, Manufacturer`

Comment: interesting, never seen that command before. So I take it there wouldn't be a log or something with this info anywhere unless I made it a point to do it myself?

Comment: See [Retrieving System Information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156538.aspx) on TechNet, as it describes the mapping between what is displayed in the *System Information* snapin (very similar to `msinfo32`) and WMI.