# System Information shows incorrect System Model and Manufacturer

Tags: windows, windows-10, wmic

Three or four years ago I somehow changed my computer manufacturer and model information whilst dual booting multiple operating systems on my PC. Now whenever I run `msinfo32` (System Information) it shows the Manufacturer and Model as `Apple Computer, Inc` and `MacPro1,1`.

Where does Windows get this information and how can I revert these fields back to something sensible? I built the PC myself so there is technically no Manufacturer or Model name.

I found [a related question](https://superuser.com/questions/298211/where-does-msinfo32-exe-get-its-data-from) based on which I tried changing the relevant values in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System` but the values reverted after rebooting the PC. I also tried using [WMIC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779482(v=ws.10)) (Windows Management Instructions Command-line) with the command `wmic computersystem set manufacturer="System manufacturer"` but on rebooting that also hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

WMIC .. the `I` stands for instrumentation, not instructions.. and in this case, it is not going to help you.

Steer yourself to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation` and edit away.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-change-oem-information-windows

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I believe those registry keys affect the fields in System Information but the references to Apple are still present somewhere. I've since discovered the values are in the BIOS before Windows loads. Re-flashing the BIOS has not removed them.